# A3 poster latex

Tags: posters

I need to make an A3 poster in Latex and I have seen a lot of A0 poster templates, but when I try to set the A3 size the font is huge. Any A3  poster template?  or which is the best package to use?

Comment: can't you set the normal font size as well? which class you intend to use? A minimal example would help.

Comment: I am trying to use this template:  http://www.latextemplates.com/template/a0poster-portrait-poster  which uses \documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}  but when I change it to a3, the writing size is huge @thewaywewalk.

Comment: all the A series paper is the same aspect ratio so you can design to A0 or A4 or whatever's convenient and just print to A3.

Comment: Besides increasing the font size, what exactly poster class do for you?  Does it really serve any useful function?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B not really: it's more or less same as existing one, so I voted for that instead

Answer (score 2):

I admit it's a workaround to your problem, but I always resized my posters later with gs, in case I needed it [PDF resizing with ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446552/resizing-a-pdf-using-ghostscript).